# displayName with variable in azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, pipeline

I have build a yaml pipeline which has multiple stages in them.
To ensure all the stages are using the same git tag, I am trying to display the git tag in the displayName of each stage.

I have a job within the stage which goes and finds the git tag

```
stages:
  - stage : stageA
    jobs:
        - job: Tag
          steps:
            - bash: |
                tag=`git describe --tags --abbrev=0` && echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=version_tag;isOutput=true]$tag"
                echo "$tag"
              name: setTag
```

How can I use the $tag under displayName in the next stage of the pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I use the $tag under displayName in the next stage of the
> pipeline?

No, runtime variables are absolutely impossible to get in compile time. The values of display name are captured before any of the stage actually run, unless you pass a compile-time expression, otherwise anything will be handled as 'string'.

Take a look of this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax

Only this situation can work:

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    steps:
     - bash: |
          tag="testtag"
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myStageVal;isOutput=true]$tag"
       name: MyOutputVar
- stage: B
  dependsOn: A
  jobs:
  - job: B1
    variables:
      myStageAVar: $[stageDependencies.A.A1.outputs['MyOutputVar.myStageVal']]
    steps:
      - bash: echo $(myStageAVar)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I can get them within the step of my next stage as you have done above. But agree with you there is no way I can get that displayed under stage name.